# Не отображаются картинки когда открываю через браузер Index.html

Tags: html, css, localhost

Не отображаются фотографии когда открываю через браузер Index.html, а когда через Vs code Live server все фотографии видно. Т.е через этот http://127.1.1.1:3300/index.html адрес все норм работает, а когда такой путь file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/NewWebProjekt/index.html картинки не высвечиваются.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажи свой код, так будет легче помочь

Answer (score 1):

У вас, скорее всего, проблема с путями к картинкам. Желательно не ставить `/` в начале пути, а сразу указывать путь: если у вас есть папка с названием `img` в корне сайта (где лежит `index.html`), то пишите путь так:

`"img/картинка.png"`

вместо

`"/img/картинка.png"`

Comment: Да дело было в пути. Я поставил ../ и все норм стало!) спасибо!